# page loses focus on jqgrid onselect and focus on generated chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid, c3

I have a analytics module which is based on bootstrap 3, angular, grid by JQgrid and graphs by C3. The problem is when I go to the grid and select a row in JQgrid it looses focus and scrolls back to the top where new graph is generated,

**focus when grid is clicked:**

[image]

and you have to scroll down everytime the graph is changed onSelect of rows.

**After selection grid looses focus and starts to focus on the chart:**

[image]

And it keeps happening when you select a row and it becomes annoying to go back down everytime to select a row. Is there a way to not loose focus when chart is generated. I can't create a JSFiddle as the page is dynamic and have lots of nested code and javascript files attached to it.

**The Gif of the issue:-**
[image]

**Jqgrid Config:-**
[jqgrid config pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nwHDsCC5)

**c3 Config:-**
[c3 chart pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tVTnUTqK)

Answer (score 1):

I strictly recommend you to use Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start) and examine `id` attributes of the rows (rowids) of grids and subtrids. I suppose that you have **id duplicates**. You should *always* use `idPrefix` option of jqGrid in every subgrid scenario or even if you have more as one grid on the same page. Typical value of `idPrefix` option of subgrid looks like `idPrefix: "s_" + rowid + "_"`.

Comment: Hi Oleg thanks for your reply, I already have that implementation of rowid. my rowID is something like `summaryGrid_16063ed801c36632ccabad6552000f82_t`

Comment: @SulemanMirza: Which version of jqGid you use? To tell the trust I didn't full understand your description of the problem which you have. You can at least use program like [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) to create animated GIF which **shows** the problem. Without you post the code one can still only guess and you will have to debug the code yourself.

Comment: I have put a GIF and also jqgrid config in pastebin. So issue is when ever you select a subgrid Row the page looses focus from the grid and jumps up to the chart generated. So a user have to go back down again to select more subgrid Rows.

Comment: @SulemanMirza: **Which version of jqGid you use?** Which options of jqGrid you use: virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1`), use `beforeSelectRow`, `onSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` callback, .... Do you use `scrollrows: true` option in subgrid?

Comment: I am using Jqgrid 4.6.0 and didn't used scrollrows option. because the jqgrid is fixed in height, and there is no vertical scroll in it. I think the problem is more bootstrap or C3 related.